# order posts on one category by order

Tags: php, wordpress

I already searched for solutions but have no idea where to put PHP code found on this site. No one shows how to edit CSS for the years list. I want to make a certain category to show all posts in gallery mode (grid) and to make it yearly filtered exactly like this one: 
[items in grid](http://www.collagevintage.com/category/lookbook/?Y=2015). Please excuse me but I really don't know how to explain it better than showing this example and I really don't want to make an ad or a link to this website. I have not found any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Such things are usually accomplished by the use of an archieves.php file in the root of your wordpress theme directory. 
So I would suggest just find this file and edit it to your needs: Edit the code to display it as a grid.

You can add your CSS inline but I would not recommend that. Just place your CSS inside one of the files that come with your theme. Mostly they are placed inside your themes directory in a folder called 'styles' or 'css'. Often theres a file especially for custom user styles. Of course you also can create your own one and reference it inside header.php or even import it in one central CSS file.

Here is a little link (did not look into it but maybe thats useful since you already have the CSS code to display items as grid):
[Display all wp-posts](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-all-your-wordpress-posts-on-one-page/)

Comment: my biggest problem is not on the gallery as i saw plugins that match with that need , but the real problem is the year filter and the way it's displayed

Comment: Just use the developer console of your browser. Right click on the year filter element and select inspect or the equivalent (inspect counts for chrome I think). Than you can edit the CSS code also you can inspect the element and note its classname or id. That way you can reference it inside CSS files.

Comment: thank you , but how to make it works , like when i click on 2015 , i get 2015 posts

Comment: I would consider taking i look at some wordpress tutorials or read through some documents describing the structure behind it.